# SQL auto delete data weekly

Tags: sql-server

How can I auto delete data in a SQL server weekly? (ie: every Wednesday)
Thank you all.

Comment: You can create SQL job for that

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, MS SQL, etc?

Comment: please write more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a cronjob that executes a query to delete the data, or a SQL scheduled job to do it.

For example with MySQL you can do this:

```
CREATE EVENT e_weekly
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 WEEK
    STARTS '2019-02-21 05:00:00' -- Time to start
COMMENT 'Some comment'
DO
    TRUNCATE yourtable;
```

With a cronjob you can add something like this to your crontab:

```
0 5 * * Sat mysql --user=[username] --password=[password] --database=[db name] --execute="DELETE FROM yourtable"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try this later on. ^_^;